# Display both the series label and the value in a devextremecharts(dxChart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, devextreme

I am using the devextreme chart(js charts) with modularity concept.

In one of my bar charts i wish to display a tooltip which on hover displays the name of the SeriesBar with also the value it has.
i.e.
Let us assume my chart has 3 bars which depict the population of USA,UK,France.
While i hover over the USA(Bar) i would like my tooltip to show

```
USA:10000
```

Similarly for UK and France

```
$("#myChartDiv").dxChart({
            dataSource: dataset,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'DimensionValue',
                valueField: 'MetricValue', 
                label: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: {
                        type: "fixedPoint",
                        precision: Barnumberprecision
                    }
                },
                type: 'bar',

            },
            seriesTemplate: {
                nameField: "SurveyYear",

                },
                valueAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: Title
                    },
                    position: "left"
                },
            argumentAxis: {

                label: {
                    overlappingBehavior: { mode: Barlabeloverlappingmode, rotationAngle: Barlabelrotateangle }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                location: "edge",

                customizeText: function () {
                    return this.seriesName;
                },
                format: {
                    //type: "fixedPoint",
                    precision: Barnumberprecision
                }              
            },
            legend: {
                verticalAlignment: BarlegendverticalAlignment,
                horizontalAlignment: BarlegendhorizontalAlignment
            }
        });
```

I have gone through the devextreme website but found no property which worled for me or may be i did not use it correctly.
can some one tell me which property satisfies my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through [tooltip](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/14_2/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/tooltip/#customizeTooltip) documentation, there you will find the properties name which can be used to display particular value.

Refer this DX thread: [dxChart - How to customize a tooltip](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T282539)

```
 tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        customizeTooltip: function (point) {
                return {
                    text: point.value+' of '+point.argument+' against '+point.seriesName
                }
        }
    }
```